# Безопасность Standart Template Library

Tags: c++

Слышал мнение, что STL сама по себе не безопасна и использовать ее в своих проектах не стоит. Хочется услышать мнение профессионалов об этом мнении. Есть ли  проблемы, связанные с её использованием?

Comment: Не слыхал такого мнения.

Comment: Не слышали, часом, мнения что С++ не безопасен, и использовать его в своих проектах - дурной тон? В конце концов ныне то, что называлось STL - просто часть стандартной библиотеки С++...

Comment: не понятно зачем минус, что с вопросом не так.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Как минимум запятых нет

Comment: Совет на будущее: не стоит обращаться на Stack Overflow за **мнениями**. Мнения не есть ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это мнение родом из тех времен, когда шаблоны были новшеством, а каждый разработчик stl считал своим долгом добавить в свою реализацию что-нибудь эдакое. Вот, например, что пишет Скотт Майерс в Effective STL:

> ... в области использования STL возникали чисто практические проблемы,
>   на которые было невозможно закрыть глаза. Адаптация любых программ
>   STL, за исключением простейших, была сопряжена с множеством проблем,
>   что объяснялось не только различием в реализациях, но и разным уровнем
>   поддержки шаблонов компиляторами. Учебники по STL были редкостью, поэтому 
>   достижение "дао программирования STL" оказывалось задачей непростой. А
>   как только программист справлялся с этой трудностью, возникала другая
>   - поиск достаточно полной и точной справочной документации...

Книга отличная, кстати, рекомендую. Но ей, на секундочку, 17 лет. У вас же нет сейчас проблем с поддержкой шаблонов компиляторами? Или с поиском документации? Или с учебниками? В IT все меняется очень быстро(посмотрите хоть на javascript, у них там каждый день новый фреймворк).

Когда в следующий раз встретите такое мнение, узнайте из какого оно года.

Comment: Но ведь это заявление не касается вопросов безопасности...

Comment: @VTT, По правде говоря, ни разу не слышал о том чтобы кто-то обсуждал "безопасность" STL. Да и Майерс об этом не упоминает в своей книге. А вот про то, что использовать STL это дурной тон, слышу уже не первый раз. И эти суждения как раз из тех времени, о которых я написал в ответе.

Answer (score -3):

STL реально небезопасна. И причина не в шаблонах а в провальной  устаревшей концепции, отвратительной архитектуре библиотеки и непродуманных интерфейсах превращающих использующий ее код в плохо читабельный говнокод. Одного этого достаточно чтобы считать ее небезопасной. Ну и как бы не видел чтобы ведущиие производители фреймверков пользовали ее в своих продуктах. Что Майкрософт что Борланд/Эмбаркадеро что Qt пользуют свои аналоги которые гораздо грамотнее сделаны и гораздо удобнее в использовании.

Comment: `в провальной устаревшей концепции, отвратительной архитектуре библиотеки` — разверните, пожалуйста, свою мысль в ответе. Какая именно концепция устарела? Что именно в архитектуре плохо?

Comment: `Что Майкрософт что Борланд/Эмбаркадеро ...` — Майкрософт не показатель, [у них политика вытеснения конкурентов такая](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_Extend,_and_Extinguish). `... что Qt пользуют свои аналоги` — Qt рассчитан на двоичную совместимость своих уже скомпилированных dll- и so-библиотек между версиями и компьютерами. Стандартная же библиотека - это просто спецификация интерфейса, подкапотная реализация которой различается даже между разными версиями одного компилятора. Именно из-за этого Qt и вынужден, по сути, реализовывать всю стандартную библиотеку с нуля.

Comment: @Arhad также Qt не использует исключения и активно использует copy-on-write, что также накладывает массу ограничений на использование STL.

Comment: У вас нестыковка, Называете концепцию устаревшей, а потом заявляете, что все пилят свои аналоги (= следуют концепции). В плане интерфейса STL действительно могла бы быть получше, но вот собственно концепция однозначно доказала свою полезность.

Comment: [replace the Qt functions with the STL counterparts, according to the table below.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html) - Qt рекомендует использовать stl для алгоритмов. второе - в Qt много где есть несостыковки.  Самое достающее - это мешанина знаковых и беззнаковых типов. Иногда в внутри одного класса. QByteArray.size - знаковый...

Comment: @KoVadim, знаковый размер массива нужен, чтобы кодировать ошибку отрицательными значениями. Этакий нетребовательный к памяти вариант `boost::variant`. Согласен, стоило бы возвращать не знаковое число, а беззнаковое в тонкой обёртке, проверяющей старший бит и отсекающей его перед возвратом числа пользователю.

Comment: возвращать ошибку получения размера? ну-ну. А когда такое может случится в случае QByteArray? Но если уж очень сильно-сильно-сильно нужно, то можно было 0xFF....FF возвратить.

Comment: @KoVadim, Добавлю про мешанину типов. Есть(или была) такая проблема, что у Qt-шных итераторов `difference_type` это `ptrdiff_t`, а `operator-()` возвращает `int`. В итоге все нормально работает с gcc и clang, а вот msvc как-то через пятую точку получает тип, который возвращает `operator-()` на самом деле, объявляет переменную этого типа и пытается инициализировать ее значением типа `difference_type`. В итоге идет варнинг о сужении типа, который вместе с -Werror дает ошибку компиляции

Comment: Вообще C++ Core Guidelines за использование знаковых индексов и, считай, размеров. Ну и  


```The built-in array uses signed subscripts. The standard-library containers use unsigned subscripts. Thus, no perfect and fully compatible solution is possible (unless and until the standard-library containers change to use signed subscripts someday in the future). Given the known problems with unsigned and signed/unsigned mixtures, better stick to (signed) integers of a sufficient size, which is guaranteed by gsl::index.```

Comment: @Croessmah, в общем случае индексация идёт относительно начала области данных массива, а потому отрицательные значения попросту съедают половину доступных значений. Согласен с yrHeTaTeJlb, что под ошибку можно было бы выделить только одно, специальное значение.

Comment: @Croessmah  И деградировать медленно в сторону жавы. встроенные массивы допускают знаковый тип совсем по другой причине (потому что указатели). Дальше от приведенной цитаты, сказано, что это не самое лучшее решение. И что бы это решение заработало, им нужно переделать весь stl (что глупо и наивно - не знаем, где ещё вылезет).